# How can I split a process in C in different processes?

Tags: c, process, split

How can I split processes using C?
For example, in bash, I can use the command:

```
screen
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fork() function.

Comment: For example If a programm has a hotkeys ( for start, pause, quit etc.) on a Paspberry Pi and I connect the RasPi with my Pc. Now I want to start a programm py pressing a button on my pc. So if I want to pause the program I should use `fork()`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way in C to create a new child process is the system call `fork`. All new process on UNIX/Linux are created with `fork`.

The child process is a copy of the parent process, the return value of `fork` call indicate if the current process is the parent (>0 : PID of the child process) or the child (0) or if the child process cannot be created (-1).